# obtener datos de data set y insertarlos a sql

Tags: c#

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto donde tengo que extraer datos de un base de datos de visual fox. Los datos ya se almacenan en una `dataset` en mi clase conexión, lo que quiero es enviar esos datos a una tabla de sql, que también ya esta establecida para que posteriormente pueda realizar mis consultas que  quiero realizar en un form donde estan mis texbox y mis combobox, dejo uno de mis experimentos para que alguien me pueda ayudar; lo intenté de ésta manera pero no inserto los datos en la base de datos sql:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NLog.Internal;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;

namespace Ticket
{
class conexion
   {
       OleDbConnection conFox;

       OleDbCommand cmdFox;
       OleDbDataReader readerFox;
       SqlConnection conSql;
       SqlConnection cn;
       SqlCommand cmd;
       SqlDataReader dr;
       SqlDataAdapter da;

public DataSet dsContrato = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable tablaContrato;



public conexion()


{



           try
           {      




               cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=12.10.12.151;Initial 
               Catalog=tickets;User ID=root;Password=******");
               cn.Open();
               MessageBox.Show("Conexion a base de datos imprime tickets es  exitosa");
           }
           catch (Exception exSQL)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Conexion a la base de datos imprimeme tikets no se realizo correctamente, fallo en la conexion:" + exSQL.ToString());
           }





           try
           {




               conFox = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source = C:\\mmt\\mma\\bdfox");
               conFox.Open();

               string consulta1 = "select* from contrato where aa_cont => 2019 ";
               OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(consulta1, conFox);
               adapter.Fill(dsContrato, "contrato.DBF");
               conFox.Close();

               tablaContrato = dsContrato.Tables[0];
               DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("contrato");
               tablaContrato.Columns.Add(dc1);
               Conto contrato1 = new Conto();




               MessageBox.Show("si hubo conexion a la Base de Datos fox");
           }

           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("No hubo conexion a la Base de Datos fox" + conFox.ToString());
           }

}    



       public contrato Insertar_datos(contrato datos_1)

       {

           try
           {


               SqlCommand cmd1 = cn.CreateCommand();
               cmd1.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO contrato (area,aa_sol,no_sol,aa_cont,nc,ca,esc,rev)values(@dato1,@dato2,@dato3,@dato4,@dato5,@dato6,@dato7,@dato8 )";                                  
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato1", datos_1.area);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato2", datos_1.aa_sol);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato3", datos_1.no_sol);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato4", datos_1.aa_cont);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato5", datos_1.nc);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato6", datos_1.ca);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato7", datos_1.esc);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato8", datos_1.rev);



               SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
               MessageBox.Show("Solicitud actuali");
               dr1.Close();



           }

           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               MessageBox.Show("ocurrio un error" + ex.Message);

           }

           return datos_1;

       }


 }
}
```

Comment: Saludos DIC, bienvenido a SOes, hay 3 cosas que debes saber, 1. Realizar el recorrido para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio, dale click aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour de paso obtendrás tu primera medalla. 2. La pregunta está parcialmente entendible, hay chance de mejorarla, lo que te hace falta es un ejemplo mínimo verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example dado que el código está incompleto, ¿de dónde salió `dsContrato`? 3. ¿Has colocado breakpoints para ver cómo pasa la data?

Comment: muchas gracias soy nuevo en esta plataforma y en estos id y si ya coloque breakpoints y no pasa por mi metodo donde inserto los los datos, se pasa directo al form despues de hacer la conexion.